# VB.net Forms UI display issue in some laptop

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb.net-2010

I am new in VB application and can't figure out what's wrong with my app. There is a form which has a couple of labels and text fields. When I run the app on my and few other folks's machines it displays fine with proper alignment and font. However, for some people application form UI is broken unaligned text and buttons. Any one have any idea what's wrong with my application?

Comment: Anchor your controls.  Other users have different video settings.

Comment: how can i do it? I am very new in VB. please help thank you

Comment: Go to the designer, click on a control, look at the anchor properties.  Resize the form to see what it does to the control.  Alternatively, look at the TableLayoutPanel control to also handle control placement, but that panel can be unwieldy (my opinion) at times.

Comment: anchoring controls and docking control containers won't solve all laptop form and control display issues. My work comp is a Mac laptop running Win 8.1 in Bootcamp (VM), and the forms, controls, and dialogs in Visual Studio itself are misaligned, covered, and inaccessible. However, I have a stand-alone monitor that I plug in that displays it all appropriately.

Comment: One thing to test is to go into the display properties on your PC and change the font size.  In Windows 7, there's a link on the Screen Resolution page that says "Make test and other items larger or smaller".  Not sure how to find it on other versions of Windows.  This is probably why things look different for others.  Setting the anchor properties should fix it, but this is how you test that its really fixed.

Comment: You might try testing with the different Windows themes also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, After some research, we found that the display settings for those users were set to 125% and because of that there were UI issues. I changed the display settings back to 100% and Booom it works just fine. Thank you all for you help.

Comment: How did you change the display settings?  I may be facing an issue similar to the one you faced.

Comment: need to sort this without asking the user to do this, any way we can programmatically turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur for a number of reasons.

In my experience, however, it is commonly caused by setting the Font on controls, only to discover that certain users do not have that font installed on their machines. As a result, Windows forms selects a font for you that it believes is a close approximation--usually with horrifying results. Widths don't match, and controls end up horribly aligned.

Make sure you are not using a font that is not built into the OS. If you are designing the application in Windows 7, for example, and shipping to multiple platforms (Windows 2000, Windows XP (the horror!), and Windows 8), you may find that font availability is drastically different on these various platforms.

Though not aesthetically pleasing, stick with the lowest common denominator in these cases. If you can, use Segoe UI, which should be present on all these platforms (except XP) and which Microsoft now recommends.