# Position of PictureBoxes in form design window do not correspond to their position during runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

**EDIT: I realized that I didn't tag this properly - I should have included vb.net as a tag, on the grounds that there could be a code based solution.  Note, that no changes to the resolution are made in my source code.**

**UPDATE:** When the program starts execution, the left coordinate for each PictureBox is multiplied by ~0.376, whilst the top coordinate for each PictureBox.Top is multiplied by ~0.418 . This "down-scaling" applies to all picture boxes.  The source code I have is incredibly rudimentary and cannot be responsible for this.  I also looked at another project and I still face the same error.  A simple but poor fix would be to divide each coordinate by the corresponding values mentioned above.

---

In order to show you the issue I'm facing, please look at the images below.  Compare this image, where each PictureBox (i.e. a snake, set of arrows, etc.) has been placed so that they line up with a feature of the background image:

[image]

To this image, where the PictureBox elements are bunched together.  Their positions have been "down-scaled" closer to the origin of the form (**note that all the elements are transforming horizontally during runtime, which is why the elements are in the top right corner**):

[image]

In the solution I was given (developed in VS 2010 I believe), the position of each PictureBox goes beyond the background image as shown:

[image]

It is clear that each picture box has been placed in an organized fashion.  During execution, each PictureBox goes to it's intended position (i.e. lines up appropriately with the background image).

[image]

Obviously, the original developer of the solution I was given would have not faced the problem I am.  The fact that the solution works properly during runtime indicates some kind of error with my instance(s) of VB.  Does anyone know of any solutions?

I've came across this question [which asks how to change the default resolution for a Windows 8 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185091/change-default-resolution-list-in-visual-studio-simulator-for-windows-8-apps) and this question [which asks why some applications appear differently on different machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072773/vb-net-forms-ui-display-issue-in-some-laptop), but they pose no clear solutions.  I would appreciate any help, since it's holding me back from critical work I must do.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a little silly now - I started carrying out a bit more research on VB forms and came came across this [Microsoft documentation on form scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229593(v=vs.110).aspx).  Realizing that my issue may have been caused by having this scaling automatically carried out, I then found the [AutoScaleMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of my form and changed it from **Font** to **None**, which resolved my problem.

Comment: You should mark this as answer for future reference.

Comment: I can't yet, [two days must elapse after I answer the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - I will tomorrow